# Setting up VirtualBox networking

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have planned to install Ubuntu Server on our physical server but before that I'd like to mess up with that system in VirtualBox so I know I can get it working.

I have installed Ubuntu Server 13.04 on my PC in VirtualBox as well as Ubuntu 13.04 desktop edition. Now I need to configure their network.

What I want is a private network between the virtual machines and have them able to communicate to each other. That way I can test the servers installed on the server machine. If I set the mode ("Attached to") in network settings in VirtualBox to Internal network I get the virtual local area network for the virtual machines. The downside is that I can't have them connected to the internet which causes that I can't really test any networking servers - and that's the point of testing this setup.

So I'm asking, how do I form a virtual network between these virtual machines but have a real internet connection for them? Like Internal network and Bridged adapter combined.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the `NAT` mode from the `Attached to` dropdown list.

The machines will be floating in a private, internal network - just like in average home, behind NAT router. They will have access to the Internet, yet will be invisible from the outside - apart from the computer hosting VirtualBox (unless you set up port forwarding - again, just like with average home NAT router).

Read more:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat